# How can I do something after closing element in HTML?

Tags: javascript, html, events

I have a dropdown list. I want to call another method in javascript after closing this dropdown list.
How can I do that?

**EDIT:**

I have this dropdown https://i.stack.imgur.com/QYq4U.png. When I click on some element of list or out of dropdown list than that dropdown list closed. How can I call some function in javascript after this event (closing of dropdown list).

Comment: code snippet please :)

Comment: Closing what? Call what?

Comment: You mean you want to trigger a bit of Javascript to run when you select something in a `<select>` element (and it consequently closes)?

Comment: By "closing" do you mean "The menu UI drop down goes away" or "The end tag for the element is parsed"?

Comment: **deceze**, yes! I need to write some trigger?

Comment: @Paul, see my second answer. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you mean drop-down list as a `<select>` tag and you want to generate something after the tag using JavaScript, you can do something like this:

```
<select name="" id="">
    <option value="">Item 1</option>
    <option value="">Item 2</option>
    <option value="">Item 3</option>
</select>
<script type="text/javascript">
    document.write("<p>Hey, I am generated using JavaScript after the above drop-down! :)</p>");
</script>
```

#### Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/6ua1t1en/

---

If I didn't understand your question and if you want the `<select>` to change something on its value change, then the code in the tag would be:

```
<select onchange="document.getElementById('output').innerHTML='You have selected ' + this.value + '!';">
    <option>Select Something</option>
    <option>Item 1</option>
    <option>Item 2</option>
    <option>Item 3</option>
</select>
<p id="output"></p>
```

#### Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/6ua1t1en/1/

Is this what you are expecting?

Comment: Thanks for second way!